# Connected graph - 5 vertices eulerian not hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

i need to give an example of a connected graph with at least 5 vertices that has as an
Eulerian circuit, but no Hamiltonian cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any "figure eight" graph will do. That is make one vertex the "center" and make to non-intersecting cycles containing it.

Comment: so it looks like an hourglass with a vertex in the center

Comment: Right. If you want to you can add a few cycles to make a flower :)

Answer (score 7):

The complete bipartite graph $K_{2,4}$ has an [Eulerian circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), but is non-Hamiltonian (in fact, it doesn't even contain a Hamiltonian path).

[image: $K_{2,4}$]

Any Hamiltonian path would alternate colors (and there's not enough blue vertices).  Since every vertex has even degree, the graph has an Eulerian circuit.